# Why am I getting an InputMismatchException with?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I created a Scanner in java to read through a file of data regarding a city. The file is formatted as such:

```
Abbotsford,2310,2
Adams,1967,1
Algoma,3167,2
```

When reading through the file, I get an InputMismatchException when scanning the last item on each line (This item needs to be an int).

```
public void fileScanner(File toScan) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(toScan);
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            System.out.println(sc.next());
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

Any ideas as to why? I'd imagine it has something to do with my use of the "," delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using only one delimiter i.e. `,` but your file contains `\r` or `\n` so try to use multiple delimiters. Also, use a loop to read the entire file:-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(toScan);
        sc.useDelimiter(",|\\r\\n");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Abbotsford
2310
2

Adams
1967
1

Algoma
3167
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The delimiter you're using is comma(,)
The system looks for the next comma, which comes only after `Adams`. So the input for the system looks like `2 Adams` which is obviously not an Int , rather a String and hence the inputMisMatch.

If you make your data something like below, your code would work great.

```
Abbotsford,2310,2,
Adams,1967,1,
Algoma,3167,2,
```

Also I see there's no loop to read all the data. Your code will read just the first line.

Comment: I would bu the data has to be in that format. That code was just a sample to show what I was trying to do. In my full implementation I used a while loop to determine if the scanner had any more input.